# I am not able to get the new mongodb drivers to work whereas the old ones are working perfectly.

Tags: php, mongodb, database, nosql

I tried to install MongoDB database drivers from the link

```
http://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb
```

but its not loading, but then i tried the old drivers from link

```
http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo
```

this seems to be working with no problem.

why am i not able to get the new drivers work?

my config
PHP Version 5.6.17
MSVC11
x86
TS

I downloaded the correct dll "php_mongodb-1.1.8-5.6-ts-vc11-x86"
copied the dll to php/ext folder and added "extension=php_mongodb.dll" in the php.ini file.

When i try to establish connection with MongoClient() I am getting the error

```
 Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in          C:\Apache24\htdocs\letsmongo.php on line 12.
```

But all seems to be working fine with the old mongo driver.
below is my test php code in letsmongo.php.

```
    <?php
$user = array(
    'first_name' => 'MongoDB',
    'last_name' => 'Fan',
    'tags' => array('developer','user')
);
// Configuration
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbname = 'test';

    // Connect to test database
    $m = new MongoClient("mongodb://$dbhost");
    $db = $m->$dbname;

    // Get the users collection
    $c_users = $db->usr;

    // Insert this new document into the users collection
    $c_users->save($user);
    $m->close();

    ?>
```

Comment: for use the new one you need to use the mongodb library  https://packagist.org/packages/mongodb/mongodb you can get it with composer

Comment: @skank how do i get that in windows?

Comment: you can find composer in https://getcomposer.org/ composer is easy to install on window. after you juste have to exec this comende in your project folder 'composer require mongodb/mongodb'

Comment: @skank i just installed composer and ran the command {composer require "mongodb/mongodb=^1.0.0"} to install "mongodb/mongodb". Command prompt showed  
`./composer.json has been updated  Loading composer repositories with package information  Updating dependencies (including require-dev)    - Installing mongodb/mongodb (1.0.2)      Downloading: 100%  Writing lock file  Generating autoload files`  but i am still getting error.  
**Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in          C:\Apache24\htdocs\letsmongo.php on line 12.**

Comment: @skank where do you mean by "project folder"?